# Java Rest Service Handle Service Unavailable

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have created a java Rest Service using jersey implementation.I have deployed the Service in Tomcat-6 Server Success fully.

My Requirement is whenever client makes a request to the Rest Service .
If My Service is down, I want to give a response message to the client that "Service is Unavailable"

Could any one please help?

Comment: You will need to put a reverse proxy server in front of your Tomcat Server, which can be used to display Service Unavailable message.

Comment: Could you please how to configure any links?

Comment: See `http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-apache-to-tomcat-using-a-proxy.html`